# Is it possible to reboot a Samba NAS device (Cisco/Linksys NSS4000) using telnet?

Tags: networking, nas, samba, telnet

I have a Samba NAS—[Cisco/Linksys NSS4000](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/storage-networking/nss4100-4-bay-gigabit-storage-system-1-0tb-raid/data_sheet_c78-500892.html)—that I cannot connect to using UNC paths or drive mapping, and I cannot access the built in web application. But I can ping the device by it’s IP address as well as telnet into it. Is it possible to reboot the device over telnet?

I have tried ports `80`, `443`, `139`, and `8888` and I can successfully telnet into each one. Or at least, I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you can SSH (port 22 normally), you can reboot with `reboot now`

Comment: So far that's the only port I've tried that I cannot telnet to.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Samba NAS that I cannot connect to using UNC paths or drive
>   mapping, and I cannot access the built in web application. But I can
>   ping the device by it’s IP address as well as telnet into it. Is it
>   possible to reboot the device over telnet?

Generally, what you are describing as a “Samba NAS” is simply a Linux box of some kind running some minimal OS fine-tuned to be a Samba share. So on a Linux box you could reboot the system by using the following command:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Or possibly use that same command, but without `sudo` like this:

```
shutdown -r now
```

But on some embedded systems—such as those using BusyBox—using this command would work:

```
system reboot
```

But without knowing the exact make/model of the NAS in question, it’s hard to say what the exact command should be.

Also, you would need to have a console/terminal session to the device to actually run those commands. If you are trying to telnet into `80`, `443`, `139` and `8888` and running commands, that won’t work. When you telnet to ports like that you are just making a protocol connection to whatever service might be running on that port. And if none of them are running a console/terminal session the commands won’t work since ports `80`, `443` and `8888` are all web services ports and port `139` is simply a NetBIOS port.

Comment: Updated original post to say it's an NSS4000.

Comment: The most basic commands are [`halt` and `reboot`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/halt). They come in different flavors but are always present on just about any Linux or UNIX system.

Comment: I don't think these commands are actually getting passed. I've tried every variation of reboot I can think of over the telnet session, on various ports.

Comment: OK, so it may not be possible after all. The device is pretty locked down so I don't think I'll be able to access the terminal.